# member of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm about to code a trade bot but I always get the error  he tells me the member does not work with the rest of the way, but a few lines further up it works. lol come explanation

i cant english xD
I don't understand why or what I'm doing wrong

```
client.on('ready', message =>{
  const member = message.member //here is member defined
  const walletaccess = wallet[message.member.id] **//The error disappears when I deactivate this line**
  var interval = setInterval (function () {
    
walletaccess.eth += walletaccess.power
}, 1*1000)
})
```

Error:

```
(node:12509) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'member' of undefined
```

If i change it to this

```
client.on('ready', message =>{
  const member = message.member
  //const walletaccess = wallet[message.member.id]//The error disappears when I deactivate this line
  var interval = setInterval (function () {
wallet[message.member.id].eth += wallet[message.member.id].power
}, 1*1000)
})
```

There error is here

```
wallet[message.member.id].eth += wallet[message.member.id].power
```

Comment: the `ready` event doesn't emit anything. You're looking for the `message` event. Please see [here](https://discordjs.guide/) for a good guide.

Answer (score 0):

A few things, it is not saying member is undefined, it's saying message is undefined. "Cannot read property 'member' **of undefined**". Also, I think it should be message.author not message.member.

Why do you make the member var just to use message.member anyway?

```
client.on('message', message =>{
const member = message.author
const walletaccess = wallet[member.id]

var interval = setInterval (function () {
wallet[message.member.id] += walletaccess.power}, 1*1000)
})
```

This should fix it

Comment: no author it is not further up it is also with member and there you go too.

Comment: @Fabboy the docs I read said it's author not member but I could be wrong, I don't use this library.

Comment: Error:
```
walletaccess.eth += walletaccess.power}, 1*1000)
^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'eth' of undefined
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/runner/Community-Hub/index.js:175:1)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
repl process died unexpectedly: exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As [@Worthy Alpaca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14409357/worthy-alpaca) said in their comment, the [ready](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/Client?scrollTo=e-ready) event provides no values. If you want to run that when a user messages, change `'ready'` to `'message'`. If you want to do something other than this, please comment it below.